Using Entra ID Federated Identity Credentials with Flask
I'm looking for guidance on how to adjust client settings to authenticate against an Entra ID application that uses Federated Identity Credentials.  This setup does not use a client secret and when I try to obtain an auth token I see this error:
nvalid_client
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. 

My code is based on the github sample provided here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp
